# ¿Cómo compartir un repositorio privado mediante una URL?

Tags: github

¿Cómo crear un repositorio "no listado" en GitHub?

Es decir, uno que solamente sea accesible por medio de un enlace en el navegador, no hablo de añadir un "colaborador", sino de tener este como oculto y que cualquier persona con el enlace lo pueda acceder.

¿En caso de que esa opción no exista que alternativas a GitHub la poseen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa https://gitfront.io/. Los pasos a seguir son:

1. Visita la página de  https://gitfront.io/ y presiona en `Get Started`.
2. Presiona en agregar repositorio (`Add Repository`).
3. Copia el enlace al repositorio privado que deseas compartir usando SSH. Debe lucir algo como `git@github.com:tu_usuario/repo_name.git`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Pégalo en donde dice `Repository URL`. Presiona `Add`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. Copia la key que se muestra en el cuadro de texto y presiona en `Open repository Deploy keys on GitHub.`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6. Agrega la deploy key a github.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

7. Presiona `Build` y te generará una url que puedes ver y compartir presionando en el botón View.

Comment: ¡Súper! Te lo agradezco demasiado.